# Start @daily Airflow dynamic DAGs right after creation

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm creating dynamic DAGs and want them to be triggered inmediately after they are created, so I tought setting `catchup=True` and `start_date` as the DAG's creation date minus one frequency using [Croniter](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/).

This is my code so far, it works for `@hourly` DAGs but not for `@daily` as they are created but not triggered even they should:

```py
    # get the start date to create the dag
    created_at = pendulum.parse('2022-04-12T16:04:42.49305-03:00')
    freq = '@daily'

    # get the cron expression of the DAG scheduling and iterate one previous frequency
    cron = croniter(freq, created_at)
    cron.get_prev(datetime) 
    # > datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('-03:00'))

    # create the DAG with start_date as the connection creation date
    # minus 1 scheduling frequency so it is triggered right after its 
    # creation (because of catchup=True)
    default_args = {
      'start_date': cron.get_prev(datetime),
      # > datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('-03:00'))
      'retries': 1,
      'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
      'email_on_failure': False,
      'email_on_retry': False
    }
```

The DAG is created with `'start_date': DateTime(2022, 4, 11, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))` but this is when the next run scheduled:

[image: Next DAG run]

How can I get it run right away?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below from

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html?highlight=schedule%20interval

> Similarly, since the start_date argument for the DAG and its tasks
> points to the same logical date, it marks the start of the DAG's first
> data interval, not when tasks in the DAG will start running. In other
> words, a DAG run will only be scheduled one interval after start_date

Can you adjust your start_date accordingly with catchup=True and see what happens ?

Comment: thanks @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon, finally I used UTC for all dates and it worked, I think it was the time offset what was causing the interval not to be complete